# IntersectsWith Error while creating game in Windows8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm creating a pacman game using windows 8 metro application c#.

I'm currently having some errors on the "IntersectsWith".

As shown below, I'm actually trying to make the pacman eat the pellets. Can anyone please tell me why is there an error on the code? :

Code:

```
        var rectPacman = pacman.GetRect(cnvMain);
        bool gotPellet = false;
        foreach (var pellet in pellets)
        {
            if (pellet.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                var rectPellet = pellet.GetRect(cnvMain);
                var pelletCellPoint = pellet.GetCellPoint();

                if (rectPacman.IntersectsWith(rectPellet))
                {
                    gotPellet = true;

                    pellet.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                    AddPellet(pellet);
                    mazeValues[(int)pelletCellPoint.X, (int)pelletCellPoint.Y] = ' ';
                    break;
                }
            }
         }
```

Error showing:

```
'Windows.Foundation.Rect' does not contain a definition for 'IntersectsWith' and no extension method 'IntersectsWith' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.Rect' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: not nearly enough info here.  What is the code for `rectPackman`?  In any case, this sounds like the `IntersectsWith(Rect) method doesn't exist.  Did you write one?

Comment: @RussellUhl Sorry, I missed out that part cause I declared it at the top of the method. I've edited the above code.

Comment: gotcha.  at least you found your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by the compiler error, the type `Windows.Foundation.Rect` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.rect)  has no `InteresectsWith` method.

`System.Drawing.Rectangle` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.aspx) does, but it appears you're coding a WinRT application, the regular .Net system libraries don't apply.